# Return value of forM in Haskell

Tags: list, haskell, monads

If I have a list `input = ["1", "-2", "14", "3"]` with length `n`and I want to convert it into an `Int` list, what is the return value of

```
forM [0..(n-1)] $ \i -> do
        let t = read (input!!(i)) :: Int 
        return ()
```

I figured out that `t` will contain the `Int` value of each string from the `input` list but I don't understand how should I put them in a new list. Note that this `forM` syntax is not written by me. I researched how I should work with monads but I still don't really get it since I couldn't find a single example.

Comment: Here `forM` will return a list `[(), (), ..., ()]`. You might want to use `forM_`, but it here looks like you are translating imperative code to functional. In fact you do not need `forM`, or `do` at all.

Comment: Even using the monad instance for lists, `forM` isn't necessary. You would just need `input >>= \x -> return (read x) :: [Int]` or `input >>= return . read :: [Int]`, or even `input >>= \x -> [read x]`. (Using list notation in the last one is sufficient to indicate that the result should be a list, without the explicit type annotation.)

Comment: Okay, I see that forM is not necesarry, but if I have to leave it like that, how can I access the elements of the list

Answer (score 8):

> If I have a list `input = ["1", "-2", "14", "3"]` with length n and I want to convert it into an `Int` list.

Then you should use:

```
map read input :: [Int]
```

Indeed:

```
Prelude> input = ["1", "-2", "14", "3"]
Prelude> map read input :: [Int]
[1,-2,14,3]
```

> I figured out that t will contain the Int value of each string from the input list but I don't understand how should I put them in a new list.

Variables in (pure) functional languages, like Haskell, are *immutable*. That means that once a variable is set to a value, you can not set it to a different value.

In fact in Haskell, one seldomly use looping mechanisms like `forM`, etc. The `M` suffix usually says you are working with **M**onads, but here you do not need monads at all. I strongly advice not to use `do`, etc. before you have some basic understanding on how a monad works. See for example the [*A fistful of Monads* chapter on *Learn You A Haskell* [lyah]](http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads).

Comment: `map read input :: [Int]` works just fine if I type it in the terminal, however when I'm using it in my `main` function, it gives me an error

Comment: @BalogSzilárd: that is because `main` should be of type `IO a`. So you need to perform an *action*, for example `main = print (map read input :: [Int])`.